# Can I end the contract without a penalty?

Tags: united-kingdom, contracts, quitting, resignation

I work with a company for almost 1yr, and I signed a employment contract which says that they provide me with training and I have to pay £xx if I quit with in a certain amount of time. They said this is because of training but they have failed to define what constitutes as training, neither they provided that kind of training apart from a couple of sessions I had till in the past year. Now I'm within the contract period and if I end the contract Im bound to pay this money as training fees. I can't afford this, how do I go about leaving with grace and also not paying this money? to my proof they did not provide this training, further importantly this contract is not consistent for other employees, and the offer letter they gave me before contract never mentioned this training clause? I accepted the offer letter and by the time I moved my house it was joining time thats when they sent the contract by then it was too late for me to negotiate on the indifference between the contract and the offer letter. Please can you help?

Comment: You need a lawyer.  But what I would do is immediately start to ***demand that they provide the training they are obligated to by contract***.  Tell them that both parties need to start figuring out how they should ***compensate*** you, since, they did *not* give you the training in question.

Comment: "how do I go about leaving with grace and also not paying this money?" - If you cannot afford to pay the company back, for the training they did provide (at whatever level they have done) then you will have to wait until, you are no longer obligated to pay them back for the training.  "I accepted the offer letter and by the time I moved my house it was joining time thats when they sent the contract by then it was too late for me to negotiate on the indifference between the contract and the offer letter." - You should have waited until you saw the contract.  Live and Learn.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, for real contract law you need to talk to a lawyer. We can't help you with that.

That being said, if the contract specifically states that what you pay is for training fees, and you can actively demonstrate that they didn't pay those fees, then you shouldn't have anything to repay. If they did provide a few training sessions, you'll definitely have to pay those. That's what happens when you sign a contract, even a contract with dishonest people.

If you're looking for a loophole, we can't help you without the full text of the contract, and if we had it even then we wouldn't because that's not what we do here. You need a laywer. Or you can suck it up until the contract ends. Or get a side job to cover the cost of breaking the contract. Just make sure you are more careful about what you sign to in the future.